# Long Car rides with teenagers

Tags: teen, socialization

I am going to a amusement park at the end of the month with my youth group. I will be in the car with 4 other girls and 6 boys. I need some game ideas to keep the boys busy so they won't pick on me. I'm only 14 and would need some games to play with the girls too. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I love this question, but think it'd be better asked on http://boardgames.stackexchange.com, so I'm going to ask the mods to migrate it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Some favorites we used to play:

- [Ghost](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_(game))
- License Plate Game: trying to spot plates from as many states as possible.
- Alphabet Game: Everyone tries to be first to find letters of alphabet in order on signs, bumper stickers, etc. Once a word is used by someone, no one else can use that word for any other letters.

Comment: Ok they sound good. I think I will try them.